# How to calculate number of 1 bit's in a BigInteger ?

Tags: java, biginteger

I am solving a problem for which i require to know the number of 1 bit's in a BigInteger.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Are your BigIntegers ever negative (with infinite 1 bits to their left, as they're two-complement integers)?

Comment: How much of the problem have you solved so far? Do you have some code? Because they way you worded it, it sounds more like the SO crowd should be solving this problem.

Comment: No the BigInteger never holds negative value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use .bitCount() on the BigInteger. Unless you need to solve it manually, in which case you can use normal Java bitwise operations.

Comment: Got it thanks, but in java API for BigIntegers bitCount() it doesnt say it returns number of 1 bits in the BigIntegers. Instead Returns the number of bits in the two's complement representation of this BigInteger that differ from its sign bit. Please can you explain

Comment: 7 is represented as 000...0111. The sign bit is the first bit, which is 0.

-7 is represented as 11111...1001. The sign bit is 1 here, and there are 2 bits that differ, as there are 2 0s.

(7).bitCount() = 3, and (-7).bitCount() = 2.

Comment: API docs says:
Implementation Note: Usage of this method is not recommended as the current implementation is not efficient.

Answer (score 0):

Do x-or with 0. By this you will get the bits set as 1 wherever there was 1 in your original input. Then you can count the number of bits set in the output.